# Is it possible to make eclipse "new java class wizard" open the class in a specified section of a split screen?

Tags: eclipse, wizard

In eclipse, I have split the editor view in two section so I can read from one file while editing the other. The file I read from contains scratch remarks something like

```
// Student(firstname, lastname, subject, mark)
```

and I need to create class Student with fields as above. So I write

```
Student student;
```

and press the quick-fix shortcut, opening the new java class wizard which creates the new class Student.java and I write

```
String firstname; String lastname, String mark;
```

left to be formatted and furnished with setters/getters later automatically.

Unfortunately, the new class opens exactly in that part of the screen where my class with the remarks is, hiding it.

Is there a decent way to persuade the wizard to open the file in the other part of the screen?